# Auto generate toString method in a lot of entities

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tostring, shortcut, auto-generate

I got a lot of entities, 160 to be specific. I need to override `toString` method in all of them.
My question is: Is there some shortcut on Intellij or some external tool where I can auto generate `toString` method in all of those entities?

Comment: You may need to create a plug-in for that.

Comment: If you have a base class with ID, create and mod user and timestap, an elementary toString and hashCode can be done in the base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit late, but the easiest way is to add [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) to your project and then annotate all the entities with [@ToString](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) annotation.

Simple example:

```
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
public class Account {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    // standard getters and setters or you can use @Getter and @Setter form lombok too
}
```

Here is the result when you call the toString method:

```
Account(id=12345, name=An account)
```

Answer (score 8):

In Intellij i supposed it can be done like this :

1. Open the desired class for editing and do one of the following:

   - On the main menu, choose Code | Generate.
   - Right-click the editor and choose Generate on the context menu
   - Press Alt+Insert.
2. From the pop-up list that shows up, select toString() option. Generate toString() wizard displays the list of fields in the class.

In eclipse it could be done aswell :

1. Right click the editor
2. Select Source
3. Then Select generate toString().
4. Then select all the fields you want.

Comment: I know how to auto generate toString method.... My question is to apply that method into all my entity classes..

Comment: Stuck with same issue, any idea how its done, I mean for multiple entities ?

Comment: Working.. Thanks @Karl Alexander.